# Tensorflow - Resource exhausted error CPU & GPU

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, gpu, cpu

When I test CNN code with MNIST Data set, using GPU(GTX 1060, 8GB) it occurs Resource Exhausted Error.

But, when I test same code, using CPU(i7-6700, RAM:16GB) there's no Resource Exhausted Error.

Now, My question is, what's the difference between CPU & GPU? It's there's something difference in computing process? Or Just because of difference between GPU Memory size and CPU RAM size?(Actually, I'm not sure when using CPU, does it affected by RAM size?)

Comment: That's because data set can not be fit into your GPU memory. You can try a smaller batch size when using GPU.

Answer (score 1):

maybe your GPU memory is not enough, you could try to reduce your batchsize or the only way you can do is to use better computer with larger GPU memory.i have the same question however one batch_size of my data is big enough for computer to calculate. so i split the images to 4 of them and train them separately the combine them the final step. the results is not that bad.